# Convert ASCII String into NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ascii, aes, nsdata

I have a set of ASCII string. It has some ASCII character in it:

```
t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~
```

I did this to convert it into NSData:

```
NSMutableData *inputData = [[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] mutableCopy];
```

But it returns this:

```
74c292c2 b9c2a2c3 90c3a86d c2af1dc2 bcc2aec3 9bc2adc2 9e3d
```

After translating I found out it wasn't the same, here are the result:

```
t¬í¬π¬¢√ê√®m¬Ø¬º¬Æ√õ¬≠¬û=
```

How can I read this ASCII string properly and put it into an NSData instance.

Comment: Show the code you are using.  There is suspicious upvoting on this question; given the quality of it.

Comment: It also is very similar to another question asked the other day, by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474856/how-to-get-ascii-value-of-nstextfield

Comment: That was a different one, I got that one already, it was a different problem I have already fixed, this one is slightly different but still with ASCII

Comment: The source string is not ASCII.  ASCII is a 7`bit encoding, and your string clearly contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Is there a way to encode these characters

Comment: 8-bit ASCII does exist but it is different on Windows and Mac. Which ASCII is this? It looks like Windows. Did you try all encondings? How did you create inputString?

Comment: Try NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.

Comment: @Willeke It's not called "8-bit ASCII".  You are referring to various character encodings, for example ISO-8859-1.  That encoding will only cover latin character sets; it's better to use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: In the pre OS X times it was called ASCII or High ASCII. The other commonly used encoding was EBCDIC. I know it is better to use UTF-8 but TS wants to use ASCII.

Comment: This is not pre-OSX times so please use relevant terms.  The OP doesn't know what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
NSString *inputString = @"t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~";
NSMutableData *inputData = [[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] mutableCopy];
NSString *retStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[inputData bytes]];
//NSLog(@"retStr:%@",retStr);
```

Result: t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~

Comment: It's not an ASCII string in the first place, so I doubt that will work.

Comment: I got this instead: `74123163 5448656d 1d312f34 28522955 2d1e3d` which returns this when I translated:`t1cTHem1/4(R)U-=`

Comment: This is very dangerous and undefined behavior. `inputData` is not NULL-terminated, which is required by `stringWithUTF8String:`.

Comment: i get this "t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~" result in Xcode 7.0 beta

Comment: Yes; getting the expected result is one of the many results you can get from undefined behavior. You can also crash. It completely depends on what data happens to be in memory. You're getting lucky and the memory happens to include a 0. Depending on how exactly this code is used, it could be anything.

Comment: @RobNapier So, you're suggesting `initWithData:encoding:` needs to be used instead?  That's pretty subtle.

Comment: That's one way (and the way I recommend), or you can use `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`. But `dataWithEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` doesn't NULL-terminate, so you need to pass the length somehow.

Comment: That could be easily missed and the cause of many intermittent crashes.  You should post an answer to illustrate this important point.  Another subtle-point: It's "NUL-terminated", not "NULL-terminated" ;-)

Comment: The docs actually call it "NULL-terminated C string." :D It's not terminated with a NUL character (that wouldn't make sense, since NUL would then be part of the string); it's terminated with a NULL value to indicate that the data is complete (and isn't a character in the string). They both happen to be encoded as 0x00. (But if the docs were written the other way, I'd of course argue that was right, too :D)

Comment: I try NSLog the `inputString` and that works, you don't really needs the last two line. But what I really needs is to get the NSData to be correctly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are confused about what "ASCII" means. The string you provide cannot be ASCII. Most of the characters in that string are impossible to encode in ASCII. Your code suggests you're using "ASCII" to mean "UTF-8," which is a different encoding.

The hex output you provide includes control characters that you're not displaying. For example, the second character is c2 92, PRIVATE USE TWO, which has no official definition and is often rendered invisible (though I see it displayed as `’` in some places).

The string you give at the end looks like a Mac OS Roman string decoding of the data. You don't indicate how you're getting this string, but you're using yet another encoding for it.

The point is that you must use a consistent encoding throughout your system. If you're using UTF-8, you must use it everywhere. If you're using ASCII (which there is almost never reason to use anymore), then many characters are not going to be encodable.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of trials and errors and found out the string is not an ASCII string. It is a ISO Latin 1 encoded string. So by doing this will fix my problem:

```
NSString *inputString = @"t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~";
NSMutableData *data = [[inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
```

Result after I've translated the data : `t¹¢Ðèm¯¼®Û­=~`.

Comment: UTF-8 string encoding works a little bit differently than what I've expected it to.